# Refresh/Rebuild page with button

Tags: flutter, dart

When the user has no connection there will be a you're offline message showing and a button for them to refresh the page if they are back to connection. How do I refresh or rebuild the page when the user clicks on the Try Again button? It doesn't work, is there something wrong?
My code:

```
    if(hasInternet){
      return something}
    else{
      return NoInternetPage();}





class NoInternetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NoInternetPageState createState() => _NoInternetPageState();
}

class _NoInternetPageState extends State<NoInternetPage> {

  void Refresh(){
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You\'re offline', style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 3.5, color: CustomColor.success, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 2),
            Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 8, right: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 8),
              child: Container(
                child: Text('Please check your Internet connection and try again.', style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 2.5, ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 4),
            FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Refresh();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Try Again',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 2.7, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),
                    )
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setState(() {});` in `onPressed` function.

Comment: doesn't work since I'm not using a stateful widget

Comment: you can send ``voidCallback`` when tapping in ``onPressed`` and then from the screen where you have this stateless widget you can call ``setState``

Comment: I have updated the code, please take a look, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bloc state management. Check state in bloc and wrap your button, page or app with blocBuilder. If you dont want to use state management library or something, You can use navigator 2.0 but it is not better than bloc.

Maybe you can use getX : https://pub.dev/packages/get

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions like converting it to a `StatefulWidget` (easiest if you don't have any more logic in here), state management repositories like `Provider` or `BloC` or you hand down a function from the first parent which is a `StatefulWidget` whos calling `setState()` there. You can also use `StreamBuilder` if you have a `Stream` which handles that.
Itreally depends on what you really need

Comment: I have updated the code by using stateful widget. Do take a look, thanks.